# Symfony - checkbox form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have trouble with syntax, my form does not show a checkbox in a right way. Any ideas?

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
         ->add('generate', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Generate', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Send', 'attr' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save'
        ]))
        ->getForm();
```

Comment: What do you mean right way?

Comment: I have big form and all fields are rendering correct except checkbox. I think I did't define it well here,

Comment: Which type is `generate`? Boolean?

Comment: Yas, and I solved it by removing form control class. Thank You all for qick response.

Comment: YEah, if it was already boolean you wouldn't need to add `checkboxType`. In cases you don't want to changed the `Type` but still want to change some attributes, set `null` instead of your `Type`